# TPM interrupt not working, polling inst

Tags: tpm

after I installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 and rolled out the MOK this message appears on every boot.

How can I fix this?

```
$ sudo mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot enabled

$ sudo dmesg | grep -i tpm
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0x40a17000 ACPI 2.0=0x40a17014 TPMFinalLog=0x40a6c000 SMBIOS=0x413a7000 SMBIOS 3.0=0x413a6000 ESRT=0x33d52918 MOKvar=0x41381000 RNG=0x40958018 TPMEventLog=0x2f142018 
[    0.017212] ACPI: TPM2 0x000000004095B000 00004C (v04 _ASUS_ Notebook 00000001 AMI  00000000)
[    0.017237] ACPI: Reserving TPM2 table memory at [mem 0x4095b000-0x4095b04b]
[    1.613765] tpm_tis MSFT0101:00: 2.0 TPM (device-id 0x1B, rev-id 22)
[    1.617457] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
```

[picture of what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooh1j.jpg)

Comment: Same here on HP Fury ZBook 17...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, Kubuntu 22.04.2. LTS
Dell Precision 7550 latest BIOS (April 2023)...

I've tried various settings in TPM appart from disabling it, becuse I think the function is important :-)

Also tried to disable secure boot but as stated on other thread it shouldn't have anything with this error to do...

Hope there is some guru out there that can help a simple user :-)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1295823)